# localStorage.prototype is null

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm trying to extend localStorage w/ the following...

```
localStorage.prototype.setItem2 = function(key,value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key,value);
}
```

I'm getting "localStorage.prototype is null."  Am I doing this correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

localStorage is an instance of the Storage object. Try `Storage.prototype.setItem2` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage).setItem2`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set it by :

```
localStorage.setItem2 = function(key, value) {
    // do something
}
```

or use Storage.prototype

Before you do so, make sure you are not overwriting any existing property. This is to prevent any overwriting for future enhancements to the API by the browsers.

Comment: It's not working in Chrome(version 46.0.2490.80 m) as the localStorage.setItem2 is becoming a string of the function, not the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStorage` and `sessionStorage` Objects implements from `Storage` Interface.

You can extend the Storage through prototype.

```
Storage.prototype.removeItems = function () {
  for(item in arguments) {
    this.removeItem(arguments[item]);
  }
};
```

Refer to Article:
[HTML5: Storage APIs](https://medium.com/@ramsunvtech/onfocus-html5-storage-apis-b45d92aa424b)